# Communication between thread inside a thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading, communication

I don't know how to solve this problem I hope that you can help me.

Behind Server side I have this:

```
class Baza0 implements Runnable{  

     anotherclass arraylist_handle = new anotherclass();

public method1(string s1){uses methods figured in arraylist_handle)

public run(){
  while(true){
   Socket s = s.accept();
   if(s==NULL) continue;
   
   //there I'm starting another thread that handles client  connection
  }   
}
 public static void main(){
   Baza0 baza0 = new Baza0();
   Thread t = new Thread(baza0); 
 }
}
```

Connected clients sends Strings by socketserver feature to client handler. How can I send this string from client handler to the method1 as parameter? It must use the only one Baza0 object, because of the ArrayList that must be common for all the clients.

### EDIT

can someone tell me why something like Baza0.baza0.method1() won't work?

### EDIT2

Look what I did!

I've made in Class Baza0 an static variable:

```
static Baza0 baza1;
```

and in main method I've started an Baza0 object:

```
Baza0 baza0 = new Baza0();
```

after this run the method that makes baza1 = baza0.

now from client handler I have access to method, by:

```
Baza0.baza1.method1(param);
```

It does work! :D ...don't know why.

Comment: s = s.accept? Please post original code

Comment: Sorry, I can't because the code isn't mine. 
accept() waits for client connecton, when timeout it becomes null, when not it fullfills with something from socketserver.

Comment: yep, everything compiles and and arraylist support is huge - library manager. clients can connect and transfer string communication.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't even find a method called `accept` in [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). Besides, how can it be called before on itself before it is initialized? Perhaps I am not thinking clearly on a weekend morning

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)   -look here, it does work - my teacher told me that.

Comment: `Socket` is something, `ServerSocket` is something else. Either you or your teacher have no idea of what you are talking about. There's no method accept in `Socket`. Well, the code you posted is a huge mess, it won't ever compile without huge fixes. Why don't you post the original code, or something similar enough to the original that presents your problem **and compiles**?

Comment: It's not to be compileable code, It was only to mention what I mean. Now everything works as I said in Edit2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a `Baza0` reference to Client Handler thread which can be used for calling `method1`.

```
public method1(string s1){
    synchonized(arrayList){
        //list operation 
    }
}
...
while(true){
   Socket s = s.accept();
   if(s==NULL) continue;
   new Thread(
            new WorkerRunnable(
                clientSocket, this).start();

  }
```

....

```
public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{
  public WorkerRunnable(Socket socket,Baza0 ba){
     this.socket = socket;
     this.baza =ba;
  }
  public void run(){
     ...
     this.ba.method1(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try now. It's same idea that @Tomasz Nurkiewicz proposed I think - isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using the arraylist only for **reading**, then all the child threads are free to access it concurrently;
2. if the threads want to **modify** the list, then the list must be thread-safe;
3. if the modification involves **many steps** (reading and writing), then you must use `synchronized` blocks within which a "transaction" with the list happens.

Comment: clients can add, delete, read new elements, but i thought that it works like: i'm sending a string from client in format: "<number of task> $param1 $param2 $param3". client handler on server cuts parameters to single strings and now should run the method.
same with reading but client handler needs to get from somwehere the result of methods inside Baza0.

Answer (score 1):

Your client thread must have a reference to that `ArrayList` - directly or (better) indirectly. Simplest way to do this is to pass `Baza0` instance (`this`) to the client thread:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {

    private final Baza0 baza;

    public Client(Baza0 baza) {
        this.baza = baza;
    }

    public void run() {
        //...
        baza.method1("Some string");
    }

}
```

When you create your `Client` thread simply pass `this`:

```
new Thread(new Client(this)).start();
```

Important thread safety issue: `method1()` has to be synchronized or your `ArrayList` must be thread-safe.

Comment: but the client needs to be run on another pc in network, that are socketservers for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say what @Marko Topolnik said. Also I have a book [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) (that right now is not responding to me :-() or a link that led me to the book, in the blog [The Java Specialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue125.html) for handling thread issues. The book has examples of all queues, concurrent, synchronized lists, ways to implement code to do several things, etc, and all pretty straight forward, an example and a few paragraphs of every subject.